# smartsheet api get sheet method giving error

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I am new to smartsheet and using api. Am getting the below error for get_sheet line 'type' object has no attribute `__getitem__`
Please tell me what's wrong.

I had seen people using this code and getting response. Don't know what is wrong.

```py
sheet_id='0823....'
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet('6av...')
my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update.py", line 25, in <module>
    my_sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\sheets.py", line 517, in get_sh
eet
    response = self._base.request(prepped_request, expected, _op)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 243, in re
quest
    native = res.native(expected)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\smartsheet.py", line 517, in na
tive
    obj = class_(data, self._base)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\sheet.py", line 82, in _
_init__
    deserialize(self, props)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\util.py", line 130, in deserial
ize
    setattr(obj, key_, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\sheet.py", line 98, in _
_setattr__
    super(Sheet, self).__setattr__(key, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\models\sheet.py", line 170, in
effective_attachment_options
    self._effective_attachment_options.load(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\types.py", line 310, in load
    (EnumeratedValue(self.__enum, item)) for item in value
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\types.py", line 266, in __init_
_
    self.set(value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\smartsheet\types.py", line 275, in set
    self._value = self.__enum[value]
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Is there more to your code? Running this code myself I don't get any errors and it runs without throwing an exception. Have you made sure to install the Smartsheet Python SDK? Instructions on that are here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk#installation

Comment: @daveskull81 I have already installed the smartsheet python sdk. I have just updated the full error after removing try catch..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for enum34 in your installed packages. Run `pip list`. I'm not positive but I believe I have seen this before and it was a missing enum dependency.

Comment: @user10257779 Thanks for updating the error with the full stack trace. I agree with timwells on this. It looks like it could be a dependency issue. Try running the command timwells gave above and see if enum34 is installed. If not try installing it from pip and see if the error continues with your code.